# How to stop InternetSharing overwriting /etc/bootpd.plist

Tags: network, bash, internet-sharing, macos

I set up a `/etc/bootpd.plist` so as to protect my wireless network,
and to manage statically attributed IP addresses.

Unfortunatly, when I start `InternetSharing`, this file is overwritten
by a plist which I didn't find the source of.

---

How may I avoid `InternetSharing` overwriting this file?

Where is the source of this file overwriting `/etc/bootpd.plist`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Source of the problem

By studying the processes spawned by `InternetSharing` (with the help of `opensnoop` and debugging shell scripts) I finally built a
way to circumvent this systematic, undocumented and stupid overwriting of `/etc/bootpd.plist`.

`InternetSharing` creates a minimal `/etc/bootpd.plist` and then
spawns 2 processes:

```
/usr/libexec/bootpd
/usr/libexec/natpmpd
```

### Solution

I replaced the original bootpd by a wrapper, a simple shell script in charge of
putting my source of `/etc/bootpd.plist` in place before firing the
original `bootpd` code. Of course most of these commands have to be
run as `root`.

```
/usr/bin/sudo -s    
cd /usr/libexec

# make a backup copy of the original binary bootpd
# but avoid to do it twice
if [ -f bootpd.orig ] ; then
    echo "already run" >&2
    exit 2
fi
mv bootpd bootpd.orig

# create the shell script which will first install the wanted
# bootpd.plist and then fire the original bootpd with the
# correctly quoted original list of arguments "$@"
cat >bootpd <<eof
#!/bin/sh
cp /etc/bootpd.plist.src /etc/bootpd.plist
exec /usr/libexec/bootpd.orig "$@"
eof

# make this shell script executable
chmod 755 bootpd

cd /etc

# create the "source" bootpd.plist.src which will be copied every
# time by the above shell script and will cancel the copy made by
# "InternetSharing"
cat >bootpd.plist.src <<eof
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>allow</key>
    <array>
            <string>00:00:00:00:00:00</string>
            <string>...
    </array>
    <key>deny</key>
    <array>
            <string>...
    </array>
    <key>Subnets</key>
    <array>
            <dict>
                    <key>_creator</key>
                    <string>dan</string>
                    <key>allocate</key>
                    <true/>
                    <key>dhcp_router</key>
                    <string>10.0.2.1</string>
                    <key>lease_max</key>
                    <integer>86400</integer>
                    <key>lease_min</key>
                    <integer>86400</integer>
                    <key>name</key>
                    <string>10.0.2/24</string>
                    <key>net_address</key>
                    <string>10.0.2.0</string>
                    <key>net_mask</key>
                    <string>255.255.255.0</string>
                    <key>net_range</key>
                    <array>
                            <string>10.0.2.2</string>
                            <string>10.0.2.31</string>
                    </array>
            </dict>
    </array>
    <key>bootp_enabled</key>
    <false/>
    <key>detect_other_dhcp_server</key>
    <true/>
    <key>dhcp_enabled</key>
    <array>
            <string>en1</string>
    </array>
    <key>use_server_config_for_dhcp_options</key>
    <false/>
</dict>
</plist>
eof
```

The 2 arrays `allow` and `deny` let me define exactly which MAC
addresses I will accept within my shared network and which one I
will banish.

This protection is far from bullet proof, but is better than the
total lack of protection provided by InternetSharing on a WEP Fi-Fi
network .

Hopefully with more recent versions of MacOS, it's even possible to use WPA3 and 802.1X access to the WAN.

---

### Compatibility with OS upgrades

To avoid any trouble with any OS upgrade which might fix `/usr/libexec/bootpd`, here is the shell script I run before any OS upgrade:

```
/usr/bin/sudo -s    
cd /usr/libexec

# reset into place the backup copy of the original binary bootpd
mv bootpd.orig bootpd

# go back to a safe working uid
exit
```

### Compatibility with OS versions

This shell script is working on:

- `Lion`
- `Mountain Lion`
- `Mavericks`
- `Yosemite`
- `High Sierra`

### Attack monitoring

With the option `-v` passed to `bootpd`, I have a logging of MAC addresses
which attempted to request an IP address but were rejected.

To pass this option `-v` to bootpd I inserted it in my `bootpd` wrapper:

```
#!/bin/sh
cp /etc/bootpd.plist.src /etc/bootpd.plist
exec /usr/libexec/bootpd.orig -v "$@"
```

Comment: What one needs to do is: 1. create a file with the contents from the post (script part). 2. run as root (su, can be enabled from Directory Utility in macOS). 3. run the script.

Comment: I also had to disable system integrity protection https://stackoverflow.com/a/49584263/611055

Comment: Please add a bold note that script cannot be run twice.. Might save someone's time

Comment: *"WEP Fi-fi network"* - Do you mean "WEP Wi-Fi network"?

Comment: @Thinkr : "Fi-Fi network" means a joke network for the child as in Disney cartoons. WEP is an historical example of "false security" category "empty extinguisher".

Comment: Ha! Alright. xD

Answer (score 1):

I tried the script replacement trick above and found it very useful!
Many thanks!

At my configuration the only additional requirement was to change the bootpd.plist from:

```
<key>use_server_config_for_dhcp_options</key>
<false/>
```

to:

```
<key>use_server_config_for_dhcp_options</key>
<true/>
```

what instantly opens DNS support to my DHCP clients.

I guess one should remark that any later change of the Internet Sharing configuration will require additional change of the "/etc/bootpd.plist.src" by copying from the current "/etc/bootpd.plist".

In any way the for longer existing conflict between Internet Sharing and Server.app related to DHCP service shall be urgently solved at later Mountain Lion Server versions!