# Better Internet Sharing

Tags: osx-server, internet-sharing

I'm using OS X Server as a server and access point using built in Internet Sharing. But it really lacks configuration options, IPv6, DHCP server settings and much more. Is there an alternative or an advanced configuration tool?

My needs:

- IPv6 forwarding
- Changing the configuration of the DHCP to deliver
  different subnets
- Changing 802.11 parameters such as supported modes,
  SSID hiding, etc. The more comprehensive the better.

Comment: I share your analysis. If you add some points you'd be interested to configure, I'll suggest a solution.

Comment: OS X is a really terrible platform for network routing. You'd be much better off using more suitable hardware and an OS dedicated to networking/Routing/firewalling.

Comment: Thing is I don't have a choice right now.

Comment: I'm aware of this. But I have technical reasons to do exactly this.

Comment: @danielAzuelos Another funny setup I saw was to hide the SSID and name it `**********` so anyone how tried to read it from screens of connected computers thought it was masked in some way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mac OS X (I'm speaking here of Lion, Mountain Lion & Mavericks) is a pretty good system to build a secured network access. But I can't agree more with your analysis: it really lacks any GUI to manage configuration.

For example, to be able to manage correctly `DHCP`, I finally set up a
highly inelegant way to circumvent the way `InternetSharing` is blocking any attempt to configure it.
This method may cause problem with any MacOS X update, so I have
to remove my modifications before any OS update.

Here is the technic I used with a solid success on a small network: [How to stop InternetSharing overwriting `/etc/bootpd.plist`](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/49476/22003) .

I haven't yet tested my `/etc/bootpd.plist` to enable distributing IPv6
addresses, but I'm pretty sure it would be working by defining the
correct `<key>net_range</key>` entry.

Comment: Is there a comprehensive manual on bootpd.plist?

Comment: The highest level of documentation I found is `man bootpd`. Next level came from private investigation with `ps`, `opensnoop`, `lastcomm`, options `-d` & `-v` of `InternetSharing` :(.
I'd love to find a correct documentation :).