# MAC Filtering in Internet Sharing

Tags: security, internet-sharing, mac-address

How can I enable MAC Filtering on my MAC OSX 10.9.4?
I tried adding

```
<key>allow</key> <array> <string>0:17:43:a3:2d:45</string> </array>
```

to my `/etc/bootpd.plist`, but every time I change it and start Internet Sharing again, it gets replaced again. How can I change this permanently?

Comment: "This is not a bug, this is a feature". The objective I imagine behind this systematic overwriting is to avoid users to temper with this file. To let users edit this `/etc/bootpd.plist` would have needed some documentation writing and some tools to check its syntax before starting `bootpd`. This is a lot of work, a lot of support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this method I used for many years on `Lion` and `Mountain Lion`: [How to stop InternetSharing overwriting /etc/bootpd.plist](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/49476/22003)

Since the culprit is still `InternetSharing` overwriting a standard
configuration file, the method should work.

Comment: Alright so the code renames the original /usr/libexec/bootpd, and then puts your script in its place? And then I just start internet sharing normally?

Comment: Also there is a typo: cat >bootpd.plist/src <<eof should be cat >bootpd.plist.src <<eof right?

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I will add this information in my original post. Actually I don't have any Mac running Mavericks at hand.