# How to block certain IP/Mac Addresses from accessing my AirPort on my 2009 iMac?

Tags: network, wifi, imac, airport

I have a 2009  iMac running OS X 10.6.8. I would like to filter certain IP/MAC addresses from accessing my WiFi via "Internet Sharing". I have already set a password, but I would still like to filter specific IP/MAC addresses.

Is this possible on my iMac with 10.6.8 ?

Comment: Please add your network topology. Which interface is connected to the internet via router/directly and how is the client you want to ban connected to your Mac?

Comment: I'm unsure what you mean by network topology. My iMac is connected to the internet directly via ethernet cable and sharing its connectivity using WiFi via the "Internet Sharing" option.

Comment: That's already appropriate.

Comment: If you have trouble with your editing of `bootpd.plist` have a look at this receipe which I used for the exact same purpose on `Lion` up to `Yosemite`: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/49476/22003

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it's possible to enable MAC filtering using the Internet Sharing feature in Snow Leopard.

[Here](https://wp.michaelleo.com/2011/02/eye-fi-upload-via-mac-os-x-internet-sharing/) is an extended description how to do it and at the same time overcome some flaws of the sharing implementation of SL.

Essentially you have to add an additional key/array in the /etc/bootpd.plist containing the MAC as string:

```
    ....
    <key>allow</key>
    <array>
            <string>0:17:43:a3:2d:45</string>
    </array>
    ...
```

Probably the opposite: deny/MAC-address works as well.

Please check the whole article and implement the respective modifications.